# Set foreground of a child window (?) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set the foreground of a window in Visual Studio.

What i've tried:

When i have 2 windows "docked" side by side i can't set the foreground of a window under the mouse in VS.
I'm using GetCursorPos and WindowFromPoint which usually works for standard windows. I also tried to use EnumChildWindows from pinvoke.net (sample code 2 -https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumchildwindows) but it returns 0 when i pass the WindowFromPoint or MainWindowHandle of the process.
I assume it's not a typical child window technically or something else that i don't understand?

```
 public static IntPtr GetProcessMainWindowHandle()
    {
        Process process = null;

        if (GetCursorPos(out Point point))
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(point);

            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out uint pid);
            process = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
        }

        return process.MainWindowHandle;
    }


        public static IntPtr GetHandle()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (GetCursorPos(out Point point))
        {
            hWnd = WindowFromPoint(point);
        }

        return hWnd;
    }
```

As mentioned in the comments from Lars, it could be a WPF window.
I can see that i can only get the handle for the parent window as described for WPF behaviour but i get still null with the following code. Maybe i have something wrong? (Any hint would be great.)

```
 public static void GetWPFObject(IntPtr handle)
 {
     HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle) as HwndSource;
 }
```

Comment: `I'm using GetCursorPos and WindowFromPoint`  Show us this code.  You are hinting that the window isn't a standard window.  Can you expand this a bit?  What window are you trying to analzye?

Comment: I just mean an opened project in Visual Studio. When i open two .cs pages side by side in VS the mentioned code doesn't work.

Comment: Could it be that they are blocking it intentionally?
I've tested it with Chrome and Remote Desktop Manager (the only software with docked tabs that i know sponaneously) and it's not 0 there.

Comment: If you are talking about Visual Studio windows itself, I believe Visual Studio is a WPF application, so you won't get windows except for the main application.

Comment: Oh OK, Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hey Lars,
But do you know why the following doesn't work?
I'm getting null by "HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd) as HwndSource;" of the VS window.

Comment: Does anyone have a tip?